# Is it possible to link multiple folders to single folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We would like individual Sales Reps to have their own documents folder to create Customer folders and load documents.

However, we have leads who would like to access 1 folder and see all Sales Reps created Customer Folders and Documents.

The Customer Folders / Documents must sync so user and lead can edit files.

The leads do not want to have to go in and out of Sales Reps to see Customer Folders.

The leads want to see all Customer Folders in 1 place.

Is there a way in Sharepoint to link 15 Sales Reps Document Folder Contents as they are created (Customer Folder/Files) to 1 Lead Document Folder. Must Sync

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one library and multiple views.

```
Library
 - Rep A
   - Customer I
      - Doc 1
      - Doc 2
  - Customer II
      - Doc 3
      - Doc 4
 - Rep B
   - Customer I
      - Doc 5
      - Doc 6
  - Customer III
      - Doc 7
      - Doc 8
```

Create a link for each rep directly to their folder.  They can create new folders at will.

Create a FLAT view for your lead which displays all the documents *not in their folders*.  This is a view setting under the Folders heading called 'Show all items without folders'.  This would show Doc 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 (depending on other filters you apply to the view).

I would suggest having a file metadata field which captures customer name so you can display that on the flat view, but it is optional.